# ArgumentParser for numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, argparse

Is there a way to add an argument to ArgumentParser for an np.array instead of a list?
I know I can do something like this

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
parser.add_argument('-foo', action='store', type=int, nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args(['-foo', '1', '2'])
args.foo = np.array(args.foo)
```

But I would like to specify the complete description of the arguments before parsing.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Where would you be specifying this `complete description`?  In the commandline, or in the `add_argument` setup?  Give a more detailed example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To specify a slight change in how the `StoreAction` action handler works you would create a [subclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.Action) of the handler with appropriate change (the docs have an example right **above** [this section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs))

```
import argparse, numpy as np

class Store_as_array(argparse._StoreAction):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        values = np.array(values)
        return super().__call__(parser, namespace, values, option_string)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
parser.add_argument('-foo', action=Store_as_array, type=int, nargs='+')
                                  # ^ specify as the action 
args = parser.parse_args(['-foo', '1', '2'])

assert isinstance(args.foo, np.ndarray)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in my comment, 'complete description before parsing' is unclear.

But it occurred to me that it is possible to create a 2d array with `argparse`.  I can use `nargs=3` to specify 3 columns, and `action='append'` to collect the input in multiple sublists.  And of course `type` specifies whether it int or float.

```
In [27]: p=argparse.ArgumentParser()

In [28]: p.add_argument('-a',action='append',nargs='+',type=int)
Out[28]: _AppendAction(option_strings=['-a'], dest='a', nargs='+', const=None, default=None, type=<class 'int'>, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)

In [29]: args=p.parse_args('-a 1 2 3 -a 4 5 6 -a 7 8 9'.split())

In [30]: args
Out[30]: Namespace(a=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

In [31]: np.array(args.a)
Out[31]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

It will complain if I don't have the right number of columns.  All it doesn't control is the number of rows; but I can easily check the shape of  the array after creation.

With this `append` it doesn't make sense to create the array in the `action`.  And even with the 1d input, there isn't much of an advantage to performing that `np.array` call during parsing.  Massaging (and testing) the `args` values after parsing is perfectly good practice.

It  would better, though to put the array values in a CSV file, and specify the name of that file via `argparse`.  `argparse` really isn't meant for input of a large number of values.  It's not a general purpose file parser.  The command line controls the behavior of your code.

Comment: I meant specify the description of the argument (type, default value and all) when adding the argument to the ArgumentParser as @Tadhg showed.